# Large amount of data in backups after update to Sierra

Tags: backup, time-machine, macos

I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010) with a SSD drive and 4GB of RAM.

I perform Time Machine backups about every day, and since I have upgraded to the new OS Sierra I have notice that every day, I have around 10 GB of data to save. Before the upgrade, the backups were small only related to the real files that changed.

[image]

Is this related to some kind of swap space for the RAM or other? Is it normal that I have all that amount of data that changes in my SSD everyday? Should I manage something?

Any suggestion, someone else have notice the same thing? Is it a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tmutil` offers a `compare` option which list the changes between two TM backups.

```
 compare [-@acdefglmnstuEUX] [-D depth] [-I name] [snapshot_path | path1 path2]
         Perform a backup diff.

         If no arguments are provided, tmutil will compare the computer to the latest
         snapshot. If a snapshot path is provided as the sole argument, tmutil will compare
         the computer to the specified snapshot. If two path arguments are provided, tmutil
         will compare those two items to each other. tmutil will attempt to inform you
         when you have asked it to do something that doesn't make sense or isn't supported.
```

To get a list of snapshots use `tmutil listbackups`.

Answer (score 0):

Swap files are not backed up to Time Machine, so it isn't that.

You could use a tool like [Backup Loupe](http://www.soma-zone.com/BackupLoupe/) to figure out what exactly goes into each backup, and thus what it is that takes up 10 GB of data for your backups.